# checking odd & even number for exponentiation

Tags: modulus

I am missing something ovious here.
Below function runs flawlessly.It checks value of "b" for odd or even by the
expression **(b%2)*2 == b**,then raises "a" to power "b".
I checked this expression on multiple values for "b".
It is either 0 or 1 depending for even or odd respectively.
I can't find a number for which **(b%2)*2 == b** is true.
But still the code works perfectly.
Can anyone please clear my confusion?

```
def expo(a,b): # a to the power b
if b == 1:
    return a
if (b%2)*2 == b:#checking even or odd
    return expo(a*a, b/2)
else: return a*expo(a,b-1)
x=expo(8,2)
print x
x=expo(8,3)    
print x
```

thanks
pkj

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry nobody answered. I don't know how I ended up here, but your even number checker is just plain wrong.

What you want to do is:

```
b % 2 == 0
```

If this is true, it's even.  If false, it's odd.